# How was my Application launched?

Tags: delphi

How can I identify if my Application was launched by the user? For example, if the Exe was double clicked, or right click > open from Windows Explorer.

I need a function to determine the above, something like:

```
function AppWasExecutedByUser: Boolean;
begin
  //
end;

procedure TForm1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if AppWasExecutedByUser then
    ShowMessage('User opened the exe by double clicking in Windows')
  else
    ShowMessage('Application was opened some other way');
end;
```

Appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this? It is an unusual request. Most apps do not need, or care, how they were launched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you associated your application with a file extension, you can have `paramcount=1` and you can read the opened file in `paramstr(1)`.

If you open the application itself, a double click or Open on the executable will have the same effect: `paramcount=0`. In fact, the windows explorer is calling the ShellApi with the same parameters. So there is no way to identify it.

And `paramstr(0)` will always contain the full executable path, in both case.

Even if you create a shortcut link, and add a parameter, double click or right click + Open will have the same result.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do that is to have your app launched from a shortcut that passes command-line parameters to your app. Simply clicking on the file directly does not pass any parameters.